# GLM group data by factors

Tags: r, regression, aggregate, glm

I'm doing glms with insurance data and cause I have quite a lot of data I want to use summarized data. In literature I've seen models made with individual data or aggregate data . On   [this website](http://instruction.bus.wisc.edu/jfrees/jfreesbooks/PredictiveModelingVol1/r-demonstrations/grouped-versus-individual-data-example.html), it is explained, that the model coefficients should be the same, for grouped and individual data and it works fine.

Now I want to use a model like

```
formula=as.formula(Payments_2016~offset(log(Payments_2015))+Cofactor)
```

I have tried it with

```
glm(data,formula,familiy=Gamma(link="log"),weights=N)
```

and also with some combinations in the offset term, but the resulting coefficients of grouped and ungrouped data aren't the same. (Using sum as aggregationfunction for the offset term and the mean function for the weights as proposed on the website)

Apologies if this a stupid question, I'm not a statistician and don't fully understand the glm algorithm in this depth.

```
# GAMMA REGRESSION
set.seed(123457)
y1 <- rpois(10, lambda=13)
y2 <- rpois(20, lambda=14)
y3 <- rpois(30, lambda=15)
y4 <- rpois(40, lambda=16)
y5 <- rpois(50, lambda=7)
y6 <- rpois(60, lambda=8)
y <- c(y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6)  
x1 <- c(rep(1,10),rep(2,20),rep(3,30),rep(1,40),rep(2,50),rep(3,60))
x2 <- c(rep(1,10),rep(1,20),rep(1,30),rep(2,40),rep(2,50),rep(2,60))
# GROUPED DATA
ytot <- c(sum(y1),sum(y2),sum(y3),sum(y4),sum(y5),sum(y6))
x1tot <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
x2tot <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2)
Etot <- c(10,20,30,40,50,60)
yavg <- ytot/Etot
#  GAMMA REGRESSION COMPARISON OF INDIVIDUAL TO GROUPED DATA
summary(glm(y ~ factor(x1)+factor(x2),Gamma(link=log)))
summary(glm(yavg ~    factor(x1tot)+factor(x2tot),weights=Etot,Gamma(link=log)))
```

I want:

```
#  GAMMA REGRESSION COMPARISON OF INDIVIDUAL TO GROUPED DATA

y1 <- rpois(10, lambda=15)
y2 <- rpois(20, lambda=15)
y3 <- rpois(30, lambda=15)
y4 <- rpois(40, lambda=15)
y5 <- rpois(50, lambda=15)
y6 <- rpois(60, lambda=15)
yoff <- c(y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6) 
ytotoff <- c(sum(y1),sum(y2),sum(y3),sum(y4),sum(y5),sum(y6))
Etotoff <- c(10,20,30,40,50,60)
yavgoff <- ytotoff/Etotoff  

summary(glm(y ~ factor(x1)+factor(x2),offset=log(yo),Gamma(link=log)))
summary(glm(yavg ~    factor(x1tot)+factor(x2tot),weights=Etot,offset=log(yoavg),Gamma(link=log)))
```

Comment: Why are you generating all your `y` variables twice, with different values?

Comment: I generate them a second time with a different lambda term to get an offset term with different values.